# Create a query non related with entities in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have a problem using Spring 4, Hibernate and Postgres. I was looking for some solution through internet but I did not found nothing.

I have several spring repositories(each entity has one) but I need to execute the following query:

```
"select version();"
```

How can I do that in order to execute that native query using some generic repository. I not want put the query in some e.g PersonRepository.

It is possible?

Comment: If you do not want to include that queries in a repository class, what about using JdbcTemplate for those native queries? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Comment: yes, I did with a similar solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created a bean where the data from the database are collected. For this I did:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;
```

Then in some method

```
   String sqlQuery = "select version();";
   Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
   Object result = q.getSingleResult();
```